# Separate IP from given String

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I have two strings and want to replace IP to text.

I am new in Node JS.

**Please help**

Example 1 :
**String** : yvm8rerwla699oxtg3fe80::e04d:bdff:fe54:108495h6ujd6thur3u69cd66

Remove this IP - fe80::e04d:bdff:fe54:1084

instead of this IP some text : abcd

output : yvm8rerwla699oxtg3**abcd**95h6ujd6thur3u69cd66

Example 2 :

**String** : 4602a1i632g192.168.0.6h6df3oep3s93sv2p301zeu18o08

Remove this IP - 192.168.0.6

instead of this IP some text : abcd

output : 4602a1i632g**abcd**h6df3oep3s93sv2p301zeu18o08

Comment: what have you attempted? why are these addresses surrounded by random other characters? how do you know its 1084 and not 108 or 10 or 1? how do you know its 192 and not 92?

Comment: for hexa one I tried to replace IP because it has 25 chars

Comment: const string = 'yvm8rerwla699oxtg3fe80::e04d:bdff:fe54:108495h6ujd6thur3u69cd66'
if(string.includes('fe80')){
var pos = string.indexOf('fe80','')
console.log(pos)
console.log(string.slice(pos,pos+25))
console.log(string.replace(string.slice(pos,pos+25),'ip'))
}
@depperm

Comment: so `mystring.replace(myIPaddress,'abcd')`?

Comment: @depperm I did but this is not the right way in other case I have to write for IPv4 it can be 192. something or it can be 172. something as you can see in example 2

Comment: set `myIPaddress` to whatever you desire and then that would work. If you are searching for a way to first find an ip address you need to address the initial question of how should an algorithm know if it is `192....` or just `92....` or `9....`?